# How to implement the expand functionality for a GraphNode in Zest 1.x using Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, zest

I am going to add expand functionality to each of the nodes from the class "GraphNode" in Zest 1.x in Indigo so when a node has children then there would be a positive sign or something similar next to its icon and once clicked, the children node would be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Extend two classes from GraphNode: ParentNode and ChildNode. Make the ChildNode attribute of the ParentNode, and calculate their position and from the number of children something like a bounding-box, so nothing will layout into the area you need where the ChildNodes are shown.

Then you have to create a custom layout-algorithm. This could be kind of tricky depending on which layout you want to provide. For this http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#Custom_Layouts might help you.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is how to add the expand/collapse (plus/minus sign label) next to each node. Because it needs to be separately clickable then implement what you explained to have parent and children.